# How to load view in appdelegate?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiapplicationdelegate, addsubview, loadview

I am checking internet connection availability in application delegate. But instead of displaying alert view for no internet connection, i need to load a view or addsubview to the application. Also i need to remove that view in internet connection available.

```
[window addSubView:errorconncting.view];

[errorconnecting removeFromsuperView];
```

This one is not working.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you connected the main view to the window in the Interface Builder, this will override your own settings. The best approach would be to have a default view in the NIB, then depending on the internet connection add the appropriate view to this base / default view.

Answer (score 0):

**If Internet connection is not there**

> [self.view removeFromSuperView];
>   errorconnectingClassObject errorconncting = [errorconnectingClassObject alloc]initWithNibName:@"" options:nil];
>   [window addSubView: errorconncting.view];

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
[errorconnecting removeFromsuperView];
```

it should be

```
[errorconnecting.view removeFromsuperView];
```

You can add as many subviews to window. So whenever you have to show a new view, first try adding it in window as subview, see if it works.